# How can I get my site's existing flash videos to work on the iPad?

Tags: content, video, flash, ipad

My website has a number of instructional videos that would be very helpful to be viewable on an iPad.

The video player is SWF, and the video itself is FLV.

Questions:

1. Can I replace the flash player swf app with a different container that will play the FLV video content? Or...
2. Do I have to also re-encode the video to a different format?
3. ... and what would that format be?

Comment: I will likely be using this: http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/

Comment: Looks like a good solution.

Comment: I'm in the process of evaluating html5 video players and JWPlayer is the front runner.

Comment: Ian, I just had a chat with the guys at IndexTank and they referred me to this page (as a proof that developers like you have been using their service).
I am sure you have completed this project by now; as I do have a similar task ahead (and no programming experience) could you provide some assistance

Comment: @Max That was actually a different question than this one: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5584/site-search-engine-for-1-000-page-website/ If you want to post a question about your issue to this StackExchange I'd be happy to answer it if I can. If you are a non-programmer, you should consider hiring someone. Though, IndexTank is somewhat easy to get running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to reencode the video and use HTML 5's new [`<video>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) tag. Fortunately it's backward compatible so you can use it and have it fall back to flash if the browser doesn't support `<video>` yet. The encoding most commonly supported thus far is [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC).

[This site](http://www.html5video.org/) may help you get started as it has [demos available](http://www.html5video.org/demos/).